# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una redirección 301 en .htaccess de varias páginas en una carpeta?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Quiero hacer re-direccionamiento 301 en **Apache** con el archivo **.htaccess**.

El tema es que tengo más de 200 páginas dentro del directorio */biografías*, allí adentro hay páginas como (*pagina.html., pagina1.html, pagina2.html*, etc.)

Y la URL me queda así (sin el *.html*)

```
http://www.misitio.com/biografías/pagina
http://www.misitio.com/biografías/pagina1 
...
etc
```

y ahora necesito que la URL me quede así (con la extensión *.html*)

```
http://www.misitio.com/biografías/pagina.html 
http://www.misitio.com/biografías/pagina1.html
...
etc
```

Comment: En primer lugar, no se yo si es muy buena idea nombrar las paginas asi... Puede traer problemas a la hora de ver cual es cual... No entiendo, cual es el problema exactamente? Qué codigo tienes? Qué has intentado para hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Nombrarlas como? Es sólo un ejemplo lo de _pagina1.html_, _pagina2.html_ No se llaman así en realidad y debo cambiar todo poniendo la extensión ahora porque me genera problema en mi página principal que hace uso de AJAX. Sé que se puede hacer así:
`Redirect 301 /biografías/pagina http://www.misitio.com/biografías/pagina.html`
Pero esto lo tendría que hacer unas 200 veces.

Comment: @Damian Garcia Te sugiero establecer una regla de reescritura en .htaccess de modo que todas las solicitudes vayan a un único archivo (p.ej index.php o index.html) en el que una función enrutadora selecciona qué se debe devolver; eso te ahorraría entre otras cosas las 200 reescrituras...

Comment: Pero ya tengo todo dentro de la carpeta /biografías por ejemplo ¿o como dices hacer esa regla de reescritura?